# D3js a tag in node g does not work

Tags: d3.js

I am creating a forced graph with d3js and below is a part of the created html from the chrome inspector...

```
<g class="node" transform="translate(359.4649422050138,271.6235100935826)"><a xlink:href="/en/datasets/category/1/"><text dx="12" dy=".35em">general</text></a><circle r="11" style="fill: #aec7e8; fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1; cursor: pointer;"></circle></g>
```

I am adding links with the code below:

```
node.append("svg:a")
.attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.url; })
.append("text")
.attr("dx", 12)
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text(function(d) { 
 if(d.group == 0) {
  return ''
 } 
 else{
  return d.name;
 }
});
```

But the link inside the g element is not working.  I have searched the net and found that the a tag inside the g tag is allowed. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/935RT/

Comment: can you check acikveriaciksehir.org  the code is the same but it does not work

Comment: In your site you have `<a href...` but it needs to be `<a xlink:href...`. Note the namespace.

Comment: I am using ---> node.append("svg:a")
.attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.url; })

Comment: I have added the code to the question that i am using to append links

Comment: I have tried .attr("xlink:xlink:href", function(d) { return d.url; })...  Now i have xlink:href in the a tag but the link still does not work.

Comment: I have solved he problem... In my css i had pointer-events:none